# External JavaScript rendering

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

There are two JavaScript files on a page, both coming from different domains. Now the second file is loaded before the first as the server response time for the second JavaScript file is greater than for the first JavaScript file. The second JavaScript file depends on some function set in the first JavaScript file, so it is throwing an error.

Now my question is: does JavaScript file ordering take place? i.e. do they execute sequentially? If yes, then why is the second JavaScript file executed first and throws an error

Comment: Please show the html markup for how you include these scripts. Standard behaviour is definitely to execute scripts in the order they appear.

Comment: they should run in the order they are placed. you probably try to query the DOM before it is loaded. try window.onload = function() { ...

Comment: @nnnnnn
 <script type="" src="1"></script> // loaded later
<script type="" src="2"></script>// this one loaded first--> get executed earlier

Answer (score 1):

If you have script elements they will execute in the order they are placed, unless you load them programmatically or explicity tell them to load asynchronously with the HTML5 `async` attribute (which is not supported by IE less than version 10).

It is possible that the scripts themselves have asynchronous behavior inside of them, which could cause the appearance of them executing in the wrong order.

Comment: how to check asynchronus behaviour

Comment: Inspect the script for any AJAX calls or `setTimeout` or `setInterval` calls.

Comment: can it be a case if my both file are coming from different servers and 2nd ordered file gets loaded first and execution take take .before 1st actually loaded

Comment: Scripts will not be loaded asynchronously unless you explicitly tell it to do so. That is, the second fil will not even begin to download until the first has executed.

Comment: Peter the second script may begin _downloading_ at the same time as the first (some browsers do that to speed up page load times), but scripts will definitely be _executed_ one at a time in order unless explicitly set as async.

Answer (score -1):

If you are loading two scripts via AJAX, then have two functions (one to load each) and call the second one when the first has loaded. Like so (below is just an example):

```
function loadfirstscript()
{
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "get_data.php";
http.open("GET", url, true);

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
     if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
          //do something here...

          loadsecondscript() //Call the second script
     }
}
http.send(params);
}
```

**Edit:** Sorry if this does not answer your question, but I am not too sure what you are asking if this does not answer your question.